# WCF only over HTTPS SVC hosted inside MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, https, svc

I've got an WCF .svc file added to my MVC3 project and I'm trying to prevent the service being accessed over HTTP.

With the config below my service is available over https on one port and then over http on another.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="TS">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="Endpoints" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
                <endpoint address="https://localhost:44301/Services/Endpoints.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="TS" contract="UkerLtd.Services.IEndpoints"></endpoint>
                <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Default">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetUrl="https://localhost:44301/Services/Endpoints.svc" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can comment or remove the second endpoint for the IMetadataExchange,
since it is for the same service, the metadata will be exposed by the 
httpsGetEnabled="true" in the serviceBehaviors/serviceMetadata.

Otherwise you could "Set up IIS to require SSL", but since it's not an option..

hope this helps.